# Missing Plug-In When Opening Project in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've inherited a java project that appears to have been developed using the NetBeans IDE.

It contains a nbproject subdirectory.

When I try to open the project using NetBeans 6.9 it reports the following error in the Project Name text box:

```
<unrecognized project; missing plug-in?>
```

How can I determine which plug-in it is looking for?

Comment: What's the value of <type> in project.xml ?

Comment: <type>org.netbeans.modules.web.project</type>

Comment: you should check subfolder nbproject and file project.xml. Third line (`<type>`) will say what type of project you need.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See what's the value of `<type>` in `project.xml`. In your case it is `<type>org.netbeans.modules.web.project</type>`. When you look up this project type on the internet you will find out that you should **try installing 'Java Web and EE' plugin**.

Comment: I installed the "Java Web Applications" Plugin and that resolved it, thanks!  Sure would be nice if it gave a more detailed error message.

Comment: It's like expecting someone who's got a book in foreign language he'd never seen before, to say what dictionary he needs to read it. Sure, displaying project type as deined in project.xml could help a little, but that's about all information NB could give you.

Comment: Need the project type "org.netbeans.modules.web.clientproject"? Then you are looking for the PlugIn "HTML5 Kit".

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when i tried to open a symfony project ! Fortunetely, i solved this problem in Netbeans :
tools > plugins then i installed php

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since Netbeans doesn't leave a record of what plugins it used to create a project, the only thing you can do is install all the plugins. This has been a bug in netbeans for ten years.

Comment: ...or you can simply look in the `nbproject/project.xml` file where you'll find something like: `<type>org.netbeans.modules.web.project</type>` which can be googled to find the necessary plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem in the future, enable a library folder for the netbeans project (preferences>libraries>Libraries Folder>browse..:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-shared-libraries