# Cannot open an existing project in Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 in my computer, I've already created several projects in that same machine, then after installing/adding plugins for Android, I could not open any project in that same machine. How do I make my netbeans open my existing projects again? Do you think the installation./addition of plugins has something to do with the matter? Do I need to remove all the changes that I made? How?

And I forgot to mention, Whenever I try to "Open Project" it will show a window which displays the location of the projects, this gives me the idea to go to "My documents\NetBeansProject\ProjectName", however, when I click the project that I want (e.g GenReport) in the textbox (the label is Titled 'Project Name' ), this is shown --

> unrecognized project;missing plug-in?

Comment: what is your device O.S (windows,Lion,Ubuntu)  ???

Comment: you can use the import option in netbeans to recover them. just point the new net beans to the projects you want recovered.

Comment: sorry, but where is the import option that you're talking about?

Comment: It is not obvious whether you cannot open Android projects or some other project type. If it is an Android you may have an old version and a problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748276/netbeans-nbandroid-upgrading-old-nbandroid-project-failed-see-log-file-for-de

Answer (score 2):

Try using create new project from existing resources.

Comment: Did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833779/netbeans-open-project-problem?rq=1

Comment: try : right-click on the project's node. Near the buttom 
of the menu, You'll find "Resolve references" or "Go to the Plugins Manager and verify that the modules that your project is using is marked as "Active". You may find that the needed modules are currently "Inactive". "

Comment: ah yes, many are installed but mostly are inactive, when I try to activate them it says "Activation failed: Not all requested modules can be enabled:" I tried what is said here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338121/missing-plug-in-when-opening-project-in-netbeans but I do not know what to do with the .jar file that I downloaded .

Answer (score 1):

As dumb as this may sound, take your project directory, Zip it up and then choose File >Import Project > From Zip.  That should get you back into your files.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because NetBeans did not have HTML5 plugin isntalled (after I got a new version of NetBeans). What do you know -- the error message was telling me exactly what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Just use File>Open project, then browse to the root of your exisiting project. It will be detected as an android project as long as you have the nbandroid plugin installed.